# Timing a function

Tags: c++

I can never seem to get a simple timer working no matter what I try. How do I go about seeing how many milliseconds it took for a segment of code to run with no external libraries?

I have tried:

```
time_t total = static_cast<time_t>(0.0f);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    time_t start = time(0);
    for(int b = 0; b < 100; ++b)
    {
        newMesh.IsValid();
    }
    time_t end = time(0);
    total += (end - start);
}

time_t average = total / 10;
printf("Average time of Knight IsValid check %d\n", average);
```

This takes about 15 seconds and says it took 1 millisecond. I have also tried:

```
std::clock_t total = static_cast<time_t>(0.0f);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    for(int b = 0; b < 100; ++b)
    {
        newMesh.IsValid();
    }
    std::clock_t end = std::clock();
    total += (end - start);
}

std::clock_t average = total / 10;
printf("Average time of Knight IsValid check %d\n", average);
```

But I am told that is clock ticks and not good for profiling?

Comment: There is a very simple example on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock/now) that I think would do what you need.

Comment: Dont seem to have chrono? I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: It's a C++11 feature.  Maybe you'll need to add a special compiler flag like `-std=c++11` for GCC or upgrade your compiler.  It will be worth the thing.

Comment: The project is definitely using c++11

Comment: Windows has bad precision with std::clock, but it has the same bad precision for chrono clocks. And as far as I know GCC has a microsecond resolution for clock already. Edit: maybe state the compiler you are using?

Comment: I cannot give support for Microsoft's Compiler but I know that any standards compliant C++11 implementation must provide the `<chrono>` header.  Anyway, if it does not, there is [also an example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/clock) using the good old C-style timing functions on the same website.

Comment: The c example is basically exactly what I am doing already

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you could use `<chrono>` (working in GCC 4.9.1 with C++11 and Visual Studio 2012 Update 2):

Sample Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    // add code to time here

    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    long long elapsed_seconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end_time - begin_time).count();
    std::cout << "Duration (min:seg): " << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (elapsed_seconds / 60) << ":" << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (elapsed_seconds % 60) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

You could instantiate `duration_cast` with other time measurement (like milliseconds, nanoseconds, etc...).
More info with sample code at the end: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: `std::system_clock` is probably not the best choice for performance timing as it's notion of time is subject to random adjustments (eg by the NTP daemon).  Better use `std::steady_clock`.

Comment: I do not have access to chrono unfortunately.

Comment: In the comments you say that are using VS2012, this was tested in VS2012 Update2, are sure you don't have chrono, or there's simple other reason for no used.